# Best Practice for storing Query Results for page refreshes

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a search control that breaks results into multiple pages. Currently it operates by executing the query then storing the results in a session variable. When a second, third, x page of results is requested it pulls the data from session to display the required elements.

However once the page is navigated away from the session data remains unnecessarily. It seems like I'd want to remove it once I no longer need it. On the other hand, if the user navigates back to the search results, keeping it in session data means I don't need to re-run the query... though it seems possibly dangerous.

I'm wondering if there's a standard practice that's worth following in this scenario that someone could link me to or suggest to improve the design that's in place.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you need pagination?  This will help: https://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList.Mvc/  ... and you'll limit your query to the data needed for each page. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application#add-paging

Comment: how are the results displayed ?

Comment: They're currently displayed in a standard html table.

Comment: btw, it's always best to avoid using session variables when possible and when using them make sure they expire as quickly as possible.  These will eat up resources on the server.